# External TikZ and eskdx issue

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to make TikZ externalization and I have an issue that draws eskdx page frame on every external plot.
[image: example]

Here are a minimal example that reproduces this problem

```
\documentclass[russian,utf8,14pt]{eskdtext}

\newcommand{\No}{\textnumero}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=0.9\linewidth}
\pgfplotsset{height=8cm}
\pgfplotsset{samples=100}

\makeatother
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}
                \addplot{cos(x)};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you show a minimal example of what you're doing? The documentation of `eskdx` is Russian only, so it's quite difficult for non Russian speakers to prepare an example.

Comment: @egreg I added an example in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solve i found. It's a bug in eskdx. To solve this issue you need to open "eskdstamp.sty" and replace this string

```
\ESKDputOnStyle{formII}{frame}{\ESKDdrawFrame}
```

by this

```
\ifdefined\tikzexternalrealjob
\else
    \ESKDputOnStyle{formII}{frame}{\ESKDdrawFrame}
\fi
```